# Row--wise application of an inline function

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I defined an inline function f that takes as argument a (1,3) vector

```
a = [3;0.5;1];
b = 3 ;
f = @(x) x*a+b ;
```

Suppose I have a matrix `X` of size `(N,3)`. If I want to apply f to each row of X, I can simply write :

```
f(X)
```

I verified that f(X) is a (N,1) vector such that `f(X)(i) = f(X(i,:))`.

Now, if I a add a quadratic term :

```
f = @(x) x*A*x' + x*a + b ;
```

the command f(X) raises an error :

```
Error using +
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in @(x) x*A*x' + x*a + b
```

I guess Matlab is considering the whole matrix X as the input to f. So it does not create a vector with each row, i, being equal to f(X(i,:)). How can I do it ?

I found out that there exist a built-in function `rowfun` that could help me, but it seems to be available only in versions r2016 (I have version r2015a)

Comment: Did you try `bsxfun` ?

Comment: From what I understood from the documentation, bsxfunc will compute the quadratic form for each element (not each row) of X with A

Answer (score 1):

That is correct, and expected.

MATLAB tries to stay close to mathematical notation, and what you are doing (`X*A*X'` for `A` 3×3 and `X` N×3) is valid math, but not quite what you intend to do -- you'll end up with a N×N matrix, which you cannot add to the N×1 matrix `x*a`.

The workaround is simple, but ugly:

```
f_vect = @(x) sum( (x*A).*x, 2 ) + x*a + b;
```

Now, unless your `N` is enormous, *and* you have to do this billions of times every minute of every day, the performance of this is more than acceptable.

Iff however this really and truly is your program's bottleneck, than I'd suggest taking a look at [MMX](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37515-mmx-multithreaded-matrix-operations-on-n-d-matrices) on the File Exchange. Together with `permute()`, this will allow you to use those fast BLAS/MKL operations to do this calculation, speeding it up a notch.

Note that `bsxfun` isn't going to work here, because that does not support `mtimes()` (matrix multiplication).

You can also upgrade to MATLAB R2016b, which will have built-in implicit dimension expansion, presumably also for `mtimes()` -- but better check, not sure about that one.